# SQL - How to display all data using joins?

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I have the following tables:

```
Table "Staff"
StaffID
StaffName

Table "AssignedStaff"
StaffID
EventID

Table "Events"
EventID
Date
```

I want to display the details of all Staff members except those where there is an association with an Event with a specified Date value. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT Staff.StaffID, StaffName FROM Staff 
LEFT JOIN AssignedStaff ON Staff.StaffID = AssignedStaff.StaffID 
INNER JOIN Events ON AssignedStaff.EventID = Events.EventID 
WHERE NOT Date='xxx'
```

But this only selects staff members which have records in the AssignedStaff table, and not the entire list of staff. How might I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display the details of all Staff members except those where there is an association with an Event with a specified Date value.

Use `LEFT JOIN`s all the way through and then check for a non-match.  The key is moving the date condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT s.StaffID, s.StaffName
FROM Staff s LEFT JOIN
     AssignedStaff ast
     ON s.StaffID = ast.StaffID LEFT JOIN
     Events e
     ON ast.EventID = e.EventID AND e.DATE = ?
WHERE e.EventID IS NULL;
```

Note:  This removes *all* events on that date, so you may need more conditions to specify the exact event.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT Staff.StaffID, StaffName 
 FROM Staff 
 LEFT JOIN AssignedStaff 
   ON Staff.StaffID = AssignedStaff.StaffID 
 LEFT JOIN Events 
   ON AssignedStaff.EventID = Events.EventID 
  AND Date <> 'yyyy.mm.dd'
```

You may be looking for this

```
SELECT Staff.StaffID, StaffName 
FROM Staff 
where not exists ( select 1 
                     from AssignedStaff 
                     JOIN Events 
                       ON AssignedStaff.EventID = Events.EventID 
                      AND Date = 'yyyy.mm.dd'
                    where Staff.StaffID = AssignedStaff.StaffID 
                 )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   SELECT * from Staff, AssignedStaff, Events 
where Staff.StaffID = AssignedStaff.StaffID
And AssignedStaff.EventID = Events.EvebtID
And Events.Data <> XXX
```